# Synchronization with Guava HashBiMap and synchronizedBiMap

Tags: java, guava

I am getting an exception from a Guava BiMap's putIfAbsent method in a multi-thread situation.  How should I correctly protect it from threading problems?

I create the map like this:

`BiMap<Integer, java.net.URI> cache = com.google.common.collect.Maps.synchronizedBiMap(HashBiMap.create());`

Then, the only times I ever modify the map are by `cache.clear();` or `cache.putIfAbsent(a,b)`

I have occasionally seen this stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value already present: http://example.com
    at com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap.put(HashBiMap.java:279)
    at com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap.put(HashBiMap.java:260)
    at java.util.Map.putIfAbsent(Map.java:744)
    at com.google.common.collect.Synchronized$SynchronizedMap.putIfAbsent(Synchronized.java:1120)
```

Is this a bug in HashBiMap or synchronizedBiMap?  Or do I need to do extra work for thread safety?

Using `guava-25.0-jre` and `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_152-b16`

Comment: I tried, but couldn't reproduce the issue. This makes any sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because a `BiMap` provides a mapping from values to keys, as well as the usual `Map` mapping from keys to values, each value can only be paired with a single key.  Trying to associate a value with more than one unique key will result in an `IllegalArgumentException` that you are seeing.

It does not sounds like your issue is threading related, rather data related.

As a example, this will throw a similar exception.  The problem is the presence of value "Bar" with two separate keys "Foo" and "Baz":

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BiMap<String, String> m = HashBiMap.create();
        m.put("Foo", "Bar");
        m.put("Baz", "Bar"); // Throws IllegalArgumentException "value already present"
    }
```

Comment: This is probably the correct answer, though I'm not sure how it is happening in my situation. I'm aware of the double nature of a BiMap and was pretty sure there was no way this situation could happen in my code.   I'll have to examine me code more carefully.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't have anything to do with synchronization, but it's how `BiMap` works. You can reproduce it easily:

```
cache.putIfAbsent(1, URI.create("http://example.com"));
cache.putIfAbsent(2, URI.create("http://stackoverflow.com"));
System.out.println(cache);
// {1=http://example.com, 2=http://stackoverflow.com}
cache.putIfAbsent(3, URI.create("http://example.com"));
// java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value already present: http://example.com
```

[`BiMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/27.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) is *"a map that preserves the uniqueness of its values as well as that of its keys."* This means that you can't put example.com again, even under different key. See also [wiki page describing `BiMap`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#bimap):

> `BiMap.put(key, value)` will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if you attempt to map a key to an already-present value. If you wish to delete any preexisting entry with the specified value, use `BiMap.forcePut(key, value)` instead.

In your case you could use `forcePut` and not fail with an exception:

```
cache.forcePut(3, URI.create("http://example.com"));
System.out.println(cache);
// {2=http://stackoverflow.com, 3=http://example.com}
```

Comment: Seems correct, but someone else answered first.  Thanks.